# How to update a repository to previous version?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I can update my repository to a version by

```
svn update -r1234
```

But how can i revert back my local copies to a previous version?
For instance revision numbers are like this:

```
1234 - 12 april 2012 - Some update message
1158 - 8 april 2012 - Some more update message
1120 - 4 april 2012 - Old changes
```

- How can i checkout to the one earlier version by command line?
- How can i checkout to the 4 days earlier revision by command line?

As well we can use "svn log" command and write a parser in Python etc. to fetch the revision number. But we want to them from the bat file. Is there an easy way to find the revision number ? (Note: we also use tortoise svn)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the revision before the current revision (HEAD generally) can be done by using:
`svn up -r PREV`

Getting 2 revisons before the current one, just call 'svn up -r PREV' twice.

Getting the revision 4 days earlier can be done by using:
`svn up -r {2012-04-08}`

I do not know how to get the revision 4 days before now. I'm not sure that's possible without some programming.